# Disable two way data binding in Angular 2+ (5)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, two-way-binding

I have an issue with getting countries and states by country. 
So I have a grid(table) with users and each user has `countyId`(number) and `stateId`(number).
In `ngOnInit` I get all countries. I show states when open user details or when happening editing this details. Now I have a workaround for those events. But I tried something more elegant and I have an issue with two-way data binding. Here is an example.

```
<p *ngIf="countries.length"><strong class="mr-1">Country:</strong> {{countries | stateName:dataItem.mailingAddress.countryId}}</p>
<p><strong class="mr-1">State/Province:</strong> {{states(dataItem.mailingAddress.countryId, dataItem.mailingAddress.stateId)}}</p>
```

This function `states` calls every time, so I have cycling. In this function, I wanted to check if I have this states related to the country, if not then do request to the server. So I need to run this function only ones.

From server I get array of counties

```
[
  { id: 1, name: "USA"},
  ...
]
```

and states by id of country.

I didn't find anything how I can run this function only ones. Or maybe someone knows a better workaround.

P.S. This pipe `stateName` only set country name by `countryId`.

I'd really appreciate it if somebody helps me.

Comment: You can wrap states function in lodash once function so next calls will do nothing

Comment: But better in ngOnInit hook just assign states result to property in component class and use this property in template

Comment: I tried with `ngOnInit`. But if I have a lot of assign countries to users it will be a lot of requests. My aim to show the state(s) only when I need it (expand row, edit row or add user). I have this workaround, but I suppose that I can use a better approach to trigger function when I show the state(s).

Comment: Try to use setter and getter

Comment: I tried and also had cycling.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a pipe as for countries and load the states when you load the user :

```
this.userService.getUser<User>()
.do{
    this.states(user.mailingAddress.countryId, user.mailingAddress.stateId);
}
.subscribe(users => this.users = users);
```

Comment: If I have a lot of assign countries to users it will be a lot of requests. My aim to show the state(s) only when I need it (expand row, edit row or add user). I have this workaround, but I suppose that I can use a better approach to trigger function when I show the state(s).